# calback function in setCustomState not working

Tags: reactjs, callback, react-hooks

I am trying to use a callback function inside a setCustomState hook,I am setting the state value from an API call and then get this value and use it to make more API calls, the problem is that  the function named **notTriggeredFunction**, **never gets called** and I dont know what can be the issue here.

I have it as follows:

```
  const [record, setRecord] = useState([])

myFunction=()=>{

        const ApiRes = await apicall()

        setRecord(ApiRes, () => {
              const arrayData = notTriggeredFunction(record) //does not get called
              
              if (arrayData.length > 0) {
                Promise.all(arrayData.map(e => fetchCurrent(e))).then(res =>
                  setRecord(
                    record => [...res, ...record],
                    () => resolve()
                  )
                )
              } else setLoading(false, () => resolve())
            })

}
```

I have been through the docs and other issues but seems that I might be missing sth here.

Comment: `setRecord` state updater function takes only a single argument, either a value to update state with or a function to consume the previous state and return the next state value. Any extra arguments passed are ignored. What are you wanting to do? Invoke that function after `record` state has updated?

Comment: thanks for the explanation, and you goot it right, I am trying to make sure the state is updated before making the following logic, I ma thinking that I can find a workaround with useEffect or sth like it, but is just that I wanted to understand what I am doing wrong, again thanks for the clarification

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`setRecord` state updater function takes only a single argument, either a value to update state with or a function to consume the previous state and return the next state value. Any extra arguments passed to it are ignored.

The functional component equivalent of the class-based component's `setState` callback is to update state and use a `useEffect` with a dependency on state to issue a side-effect. This is synonymous to `componentDidUpdate`.

Update the `record` state in the `myFunction` callback and use a `useEffect` hook with a dependency on the `record` state update to issue the additional side-effect.

```
const [record, setRecord] = useState([]);

myFunction = async () => {
  const ApiRes = await apicall();
  setRecord(ApiRes);
}

useEffect(() => {
  const arrayData = shouldBeTriggeredFunction(record);
          
  if (arrayData.length > 0) {
    Promise.all(arrayData.map(e => fetchCurrent(e)))
      .then(res => {
        setRecord(record => [...res, ...record]);
      });
  } else {
    setLoading(false);
  }
}, [record]);
```

This will however create a infinite loop if the effect updates the same state that is in its dependency array. You must also add an additional conditional test (what that condition is it up to you), or use an additional state dependency, like `doFetchCurrent` or something similar to use as the conditional guard so you don't render loop.